# VirtualMachine Debian after successful installation blackscreen

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

I had this problem often now. And I never could figure out how to fix it.

I installed `Debian 10` on my VirtualMachine, after the reboot the screen just wents black and the cursor blinks constantly.

I cannot login to Shell (`Crtl+Alt+F1`) I see no GRUB-Bootloader, the screen just goes black.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to verify the amount of RAM that you allocate to your virtual machine (in `Vmware` or `virtualbox`).

It may come that It is too small, thus leading to unability to display. Increase it then.